# Coercion within data structures

Tags: coq

The following code gives me an error:

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Open Scope R_scope.

Definition C := (R * R)%type.

Definition RtoC (r : R) : C := (r,0).

Coercion RtoC : R >-> C.

Definition lC : list C := [0;0;0;1].
```

```
Error: The term "[0; 0; 0; 1]" has type "list R" while it is expected to have type "list C".
```

But I've defined `RtoC` as a coercion and I don't see any problems when I use

```
Definition myC : C := 4.
```

How do I get Coq to apply the coercion within the list?

Related question: If I enter `Check [0;0;0;1]` it returns `list R`, inserting an implicit `IZR` before every number. Why does Coq think I want `R`s rather than `Z`s?

Comment: Are you sure coq is using `IZR`? Maybe you're in a scope which parses numerals as reals? I'm not sure myself so I might be wrong. If you could provide your imports also.

Comment: Can it do that? When I `Set Printing All`, I see the IZR. That said, if I close the R_scope, it won't know how to parse the numbers. (I don't have Z_scope open.)

Comment: Ok. Can you add the context (`Imports' and options)? So people can try it out?

Comment: Done. (Sorry, I didn't see this response when posted.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure there is a fully satisfying solution to your question.

Indeed, as recalled in the [Coq refman](https://coq.github.io/doc/V8.11.0/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html):

> Given a term, possibly not typable, we are interested in the problem of determining if it can be well typed modulo insertion of appropriate coercions.

and it turns out that in your example, the term `[0;0;0;1]` itself is *typable* as a `list R` and it is type-checked "in one go"; thereby when the `[0;0;0;1] : list C` type mismatch occurs, as there's no "backtracking", a coercion can't be inserted within the list elements.

So maybe you could adapt your formalization in a different way, or just use one of these workarounds:

- Rewriting your term into a β-redex:

  ```
  Definition lC := (fun z o => [z;z;z;o] : list C) 0 1.
  ```
- Or inserting a few more typecasts around each element:

  ```
  Definition lC := [0:C; 0:C; 0:C; 1:C].
  ```

Regarding your last question

> Why does Coq think I want `R`s rather than `Z`s?

this comes from your line `Open Scope R_scope.`, which implies numeral litterals are recognized by default as belonging to `R` (which deals with the classical axiomatization of the real numbers formalized in the standard library `Reals`). More specifically, the implementation has changed in Coq 8.7, as from [coq/coq@a4a76c2](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/a4a76c253474ac4ce523b70d0150ea5dcf546385) (discussed in [PR coq/coq#415](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/415)). To sum up, a literal such as `5%R` is now parsed as `IZR 5`, that is, `IZR (Zpos (xI (xO xH)))`, while it used to be parsed to a much less concise term in Coq 8.6: 
`Rplus R1 (Rmult (Rplus R1 R1) (Rplus R1 R1))`.